# MUI Simplifying Date Selection with Datepicker or DateCalendar (won't be modal but will be input)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, datepicker

I have developed an application using the MUI datepicker and datecalendar components. I employ the datepicker for the web version, where the calendar is displayed in a modal. However, for mobile devices, instead of a modal, I utilize the datecalendar to embed the calendar within a box. Due to the limitations of mobile, I find myself using both datepicker and datecalendar, resulting in a rather intricate codebase. (In the datecalendar, I transmit the selected day to the datepicker using the onchange event.) Do you happen to be aware of an alternative method or approach that would allow me to create an input field and open a calendar without the use of modals, all while using just one of these components?

```
<DateCalendar
  showDaysOutsideCurrentMonth
  shouldDisableDate={isWeekend}
  onChange={(selectedEndDate) => {
  setSelectedEndDate(selectedEndDate)
  setIsCalendarEndOpen(!isCalendarEndOpen)
  }}
  sx={{ display: isCalendarEndOpen ? "block" : "none", padding: "16px" }}
/>

<DesktopDatePicker
  shouldDisableDate={isWeekend}
  showDaysOutsideCurrentMonth
  value={selectedDate}
  open={false}
  onOpen={() => setIsCalendarOpen(!isCalendarOpen)}
  format="DD/MM/YYYY"
  orientation="portrait"
/>
```

"Is there a method to deactivate one of the components I've employed in the structure above? I aspire to retain both an input field and calendar functionality (which I can embed within a container). Is there a viable solution for this?"